# ADBannerView causes interface orientation mixup

Tags: iad, landscape-portrait, uistatusbar, adbannerview

I have integrated iAd banner and iAd interstitial ads in my app, and i'm getting a weird behavior, when clicked and then rotates to landscape , after dismissal of the ad, weird things happen :

First, the status bar stays in landscape(my app is only portrait), I easily fixed that using setStatusBarOrientation.

The second thing, which I can't fix is that when I open a UIPopoverController (with ImagePicker for example, but it happens with all sorts of content) the popover and/or content is laying on its side as in landscape orientation.

Please help, and thanks in advance,

Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

in my appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions i was using :

```
[self.window addSubview:myTabBar.view];
```

instead of

```
[self.window addSubview:myTabBar.view];
```

full source should look like :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{       
    ...
    self.window.rootViewController = myTabBar;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    ...
}
```